# Frame text is cropped while exporting as EPS

Tags: export, image, eps-format

I have generated an eps file with using `Export["filename.eps", figure, "eps"]`, but the text on the frame labels and tick numbers are cropped like this:

Screenshot from screen:

[image: Screenshot from screen]

Screenshot from image generated:

[image: Screenshot from image generated]

This is generated from `ContourPlot`. But this problem persists wirh `ListPlot`, `Plot`, and `ListDensityPlot`. I have played with `ImagePadding` option, but did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen this problem on a number of occasions and have implemented a "quick fix" of adding spaces at the end of label. Works well enough that I haven't desired to spend much more time debugging.

Comment: That sounds cool, but how about the tick numbers? Is there an option to expand the textbox of labels?

Comment: It will help if you include the code that reproduces this particular problem.

Comment: `rasterTrick[plot_] := 
  Show[plot, 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}];`



`Export["figure.eps", figure // rasterTrick]`

Comment: When I have asked Mathematica, they said this is a bug in Linux version, which the workaround is not that simple. They suggested to generate the figure with Mathematica 9.0 (I have tried this in Mathematica 10.0).